# Class constructor cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Appreciate that this questions has been asked a few times, but almost all the cases that I've encountered have been the ones where someone tried to extend a non-native class. My case is different. I have a very simple base class called `CObject` which is as follows:

```
export class CObject extends BaseObject {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    static url(path: string): string { return ""; }
    static wssUrl(): string { return ""; }
    static callMethod(method, path: string, params: any, noConvertData?: boolean): Promise<any> { return null; }
    static post(path: string, params: any, noConvertData?: boolean): Promise<any> {
        return CObject.callMethod('post', path, params, noConvertData);
    }

    static put(path: string, params: any, noConvertData?: boolean): Promise<any> {
        return CObject.callMethod('put', path, params, noConvertData);
    }

    static patch(path: string, params: any, noConvertData?: boolean): Promise<any> {
        return CObject.callMethod('patch', path, params, noConvertData);
    }

    static get(path: string, params: any, noConvertData?: boolean): Promise<any> {
        return CObject.callMethod('get', path, params, noConvertData);
    }

    static delete(path: string, params: any, noConvertData?: boolean): Promise<any> {
        return CObject.callMethod('delete', path, params, noConvertData);
    }
}
```

The entire hierarchy of classes including BaseObject, are just simple Typescript classes. However, when I extend a class from `CObject` and then try instantiating it, I get this dreaded error (4 days now!). The funny thing is that I can instantiate `CObject` on it's own without any issues. It's just derived classes that are giving the issue, even empty ones like this:

```
export class TestClass extends CObject {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

A point to note is that this code is shared between my Server (Node.js) and Client sides. The code works perfectly fine on the server side. No issues whatsoever. 
I have tried looking at the babel generated code and it's just simple ES6 classes. All other TS generated classes work as fine and everything below `CObject` fails when it gets to calling the `CObject` constructor.

My .babelrc is given below:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "es2015-node5",
        "react",
        "stage-0",
        "stage-1",
        "bluebird"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-decorators-legacy",
        "react-hot-loader/babel",
        "transform-async-to-bluebird",
        "transform-promise-to-bluebird",
        "transform-runtime",
        [
            "module-alias", 
            [
                { "src": "./build/Server", "expose": "Server" },
                { "src": "./build/Shared", "expose": "Shared" },
                { "src": "./build/Client", "expose": "Client" }
            ]
        ]
    ],
    "compact": "false"
}`
```

For client side compilation, my awesome-typescript-loader config in tsconfig.json is as follows:

**EDIT: I was looking at the wrong ATL config. The full config is as follows:**

```
"awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "babelrc": true,
    "useBabel": true,
    "useWebpackText": true,
    "useTranspileModule": true,
    "doTypeCheck": true,
    "forkChecker": true,
    "presets": ["env", { "targets": "last 2 versions, ie 11", "modules": false }, { "exclude": ["transform-es2015-classes"] } ],
    "babelOptions": {
        "sourceMaps": true
    },
    "useCache": true
}
```

Client side webpack config is as follows:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');

let outputDir = path.join(__dirname, "..", "dist", "Client");
console.log(`Output: ${outputDir}`);

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/Client/Browser/Src/Main.tsx",
    output: {
        filename: "client.js",
        path: outputDir
    },
    target: 'web',

    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"],
        plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin({ configFile: "./tsconfig.json" })],
        modules: [
            "./node_modules",
            "./src/Shared",
            "./src/Client"
        ]
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },

            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    }
};
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: The exact error is:

```
ConfigSection.ts?26cc:18 Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor CObject cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at new ConfigSection (ConfigSection.ts?26cc:18)
    at Object../src/Shared/Model/Config/ShAlpha.ts (ShAlpha.ts:338)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
```

Comment: Where does `BaseObject` come from and how does that look like?

Comment: `BaseObject` is my own class and right now it's almost completely empty. Wouldn't I be getting an error about `BaseObject` constructor instead, if there was an issue with it? Also, why would node work fine if there was any non conformant code?

Comment: What error are you getting, exactly?

Comment: Added to the original post but here it is for you: `ConfigSection.ts?26cc:18 Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor CObject cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at new ConfigSection (ConfigSection.ts?26cc:18)
    at Object../src/Shared/Model/Config/ShAlpha.ts (ShAlpha.ts:338)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)`

Comment: Interesting... I agree, if there would be a problem with the BaseComponent, the traceback would say so. I'll try to reproduce this.

Comment: I ran into this error once. In my case, I had a library made by me, and in my app, I was deriving a class from one in the library. My problem was that my app was targeting ES5, and I was using the ES6 version of the library. Can you check if in the transpiled JavaScript code, your derived classes are in ES5 but `CObject` is defined as an ES6 class?

Comment: @OscarPaz You saved my day, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, thanks to Oscar Paz, I have been able to fix the issue. Turns out that the culprit was my ATL config:

```
"awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "babelrc": true,
    "useBabel": true,
    "useWebpackText": true,
    "useTranspileModule": true,
    "doTypeCheck": true,
    "forkChecker": true,
    "presets": ["env", { "targets": "last 2 versions, ie 11", "modules": false }, { "exclude": ["transform-es2015-classes"] } ],
    "babelOptions": {
        "sourceMaps": true
    },
    "useCache": true
}
```

More specifically, this line:

```
    "presets": ["env", { "targets": "last 2 versions, ie 11", "modules": false }, { "exclude": ["transform-es2015-classes"] } ],
```

even though I'd set:

```
    "babelrc": true,
```

Expecting the .babelrc to get used, which is what was getting used for the Node.js code. This was causing multiple definitions (both ES6 and ES5) of the classes derived from `CObject` to be generated. So `CObject` was getting generated correctly:

```
let CObject = exports.CObject = class CObject extends _BaseObject.BaseObject {} ...
```

The first definition of `ConfigSection` was also getting generated correctly:

```
let ConfigSection = ConfigSection_1 = class ConfigSection extends Shared_Core_CObject__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["CObject"] {} ...
```

But then further down:

```
var ConfigSection = ConfigSection_1 = function (_CObject) {
    (0, _inherits3.default)(ConfigSection, _CObject); ...
```

This is what was causing the error. I don't know why ATL isn't ignoring those options and why those options cause this sort of code-gen. Perhaps, someone with a better understanding can shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

For fellow Googlers, another cause of this error: on 04/2019, using the non maintained [why-did-you-update](https://github.com/maicki/why-did-you-update) npm React module caused this error.

Removing the module and its invocation fixed the bug.

Answer (score 0):

I found removing semi-colons from the end of lines using `require()` (and in my case, right before an IIFE) caused this issue.

```
const MyClass = require("./myclass")

(() => { ... code ... })()
```

Once I added semi-colons on the end, the issue was resolved. YMMV